# Stackdriver doesn't send message to Discord webhook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, discord, webhooks, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've created a Stackdriver Policy with two notification channels: email and webhook with token authentication. I'm using my email and a webhook created on my Discord server.
When the alert triggers I receive the email but I don't receive the notification on my Discord server.

Comment: There is no standard for a webhook that every services understands. You need to make sure the two services are compatible before using them and if they are not you have to do some programming.

Comment: Have you tried to use Google Cloud Function in Go to transform / proxy Stackdriver Static Webhook notifications to Discord as it was described [here](https://github.com/Courtsite/stackdriver-to-discord)