# How to send notifications to Discord channel by Google Cloud Monitoring Alerting

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, discord, webhooks, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a Discord channel. I want `Google Cloud Monitoring` to send notifications to this channel via `webhook`.

Help me please T.T

Answer (score 4):

You can use the notification channel of webhook to send the notification to your discord.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks

[image]

**Option 2**

If Stackdriver not sending the webhook directly you can simply leverage the pub/sub with a cloud function that would be an easy option and cost-efficient.

[image]

Cloud monitoring alert will push the payload to **pub/sub** and write a simple cloud function which will consume the `pub/sub's` payload and **send** **webhook** to discord.

So flow will be something like : **`Stackdriver monitoring > Pub/Sub > CloudFunction (webhook hit to discord) > Discord`**

**Cloud function code**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
exports.helloPubSub = (message, context) => {
  const name = message.data
    ? Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString()
    : 'World';

  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
 
var URL = "Discord URL";

fetch(URL, {
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': <DARA>,
    headers: data.getHeaders()
})
.then(res=> console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
    };
```

[Code ref](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/functions/helloworld/index.js) & [Second Gen tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub)

Comment: I can not send it to the discord channel.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried.

I entered a webhook url.  Then clicked `test connection` button. It's not working: nothing hasn't recieved.

Also checked with postman with a positive result on a discord channel.

and finally found the solution in comments here:

[Stackdriver doesn't send message to Discord webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071693/stackdriver-doesnt-send-message-to-discord-webhook)